# Not going into the if statement which is inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

This code below is what I have tried but it's not going into the if statements:

```
def row_to_tree(row):
        out = {}
        pos = [out]
        for cues, directions, thresholds, exits in zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(";"), row[["cues", "directions", "thresholds", "exits"]].values)):
                pos = pos[0]
#                 print(pos)
                if exits == 1:
                    pos.append({"cues": True})
                    pos["cues"] = cues
                    pos["directions"] = directions
                    pos["thresholds"] = thresholds
                    pos["exits"] = exits
                elif exits == 0:    
                    pos["cues"] = cues
                    pos["directions"] = directions
                    pos["thresholds"] = thresholds
                    pos["exits"] = exits
                    pos.append({"cues": False})
                pos["children"] = [{"cues":True}]
                pos = pos["children"]
        pos.append({"cues": False})
        return out

trees = [row_to_tree(row) for i, row in df2.iterrows()]

trees[0]
```

it's throwing me this:

```
{'children': [{'cues': True,
   'children': [{'cues': True,
     'children': [{'cues': True,
       'children': [{'cues': True}, {'cues': False}]}]}]}]}
```

Which is not what I want. What I want is this down below, as an example I have written the first row.

So from this dataframe:

```
tree       cues                        directions   thresholds   exits
 1   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;1;0.5
 2   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;1;0.5
 3   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;0;0.5
 4   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;0;0.5
 5   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;1;0;0.5
 6   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;0;0.5 
 7   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;1;0.5
 8   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;0;0;0.5
```

I am trying to get something like this (i.e. first row):

```
{
    "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
    "directions": ">",
    "thresholds": "126",
    "exits": "1",
    "children": [
      {
        "cues": "True",
      },
      {
        "cues": "Age",
        "directions": ">",
        "thresholds": "29",
        "exits": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "cues": "BMI",
            "directions": ">",
            "thresholds": "29.7",
            "exits": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "cues": "True",
              },
              {
                "cues": "TimesPregnant",
                "directions": ">",
                "thresholds": "6",
                "exits": "0.5",
                "children":[
                  {
                    "cues": "True"
                  },
                  {
                    "cues": "False"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cues": "False"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
```

but I am struggling with it and can't seem to make a solution for it, probably as I am not very experienced with python nor pandas.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do a `print(pos)` right before line 5 in `row_to_tree`

Comment: I get this: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
[]`

Comment: that's odd, since you're forcing it to be a list, please review and provide a [mcve]. Also, what are you trying to achieve by doing `pos = [out]`?

Comment: @Yuca initializing an empty list?

Comment: An empty list has no index `[0]`

Comment: @Yuca Please, check my edited post again.